PDO MySQL 5.6 Query Execution Timeout
Going through threads from 2009-2022 it doesn't look like there has been a real answer on getting a query to timeout in PHP from MySQL (5.6). The PDO timeout attribute is for the connecting, not the execution. We don't want all queries to stop executing after X seconds so the global MySQL variable can't be used for this. We also don't want the PHP script to stop running because the query took too long so max execution time on PHP side is ruled out.
I've found the following possible approach:
$db->query('SET SESSION MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = 15000;');

run the query that may take longer than 15 seconds, then restore the MAX_STATEMENT_TIME value with:
$db->query('SET SESSION MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = 0;');

Is there a better way to do this though? I would think in the past +10 years something has changed.
Irrelevant threads:

Setting a connect timeout with PDO
PHP PDO execute to abort when MySQL query taking more than X seconds?
PHP's PDO is ignoring the ATTR_TIMEOUT option for MySQL when server cannot be reached
https://serverfault.com/questions/401828/how-to-automatically-kill-slow-mysql-queries-after-n-seconds

#4 is close but will not work with MySQL 5.6, statement timeouts are not allowed there. (e.g. MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 1000)

Is the MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(N) optimizer hint the thing you're looking for? Optimizer hints are specified within /*+ ... */ comments, which isn't very pretty, but SQL often isn't. I don't know if this is compatible with the old version of MySQL you're running.

Is this helpful for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211683/mysql-mariadb-execution-timeout-within-query-called-from-php

@KIKOSoftware Yes, but that is only for 5.7+. I was hoping PHP had some mechanism I was unable to find that allowed for it to kill when a threshold was exceeded. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54005466/global-query-timeout-in-mysql-5-6 is related but not a great solution and dated so hopefully something new is out there. I want the PHP thread to know the timeout was hit and to handle that case. I dont just want to kill the mysql query and have PHP be in an unknown state.

@Alessandro Thanks, yes that works. Was still hoping PHP had something but that will work for the time being.. SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=X FOR query

The better solution is to optimize queries so they don't take more than 15 seconds.

It feels to me like having to forcefully time-out a query can only happen at the end of a sequence of bad decisions. This is probably also the reason you're locked into a version of MySQL for which normal support ended 6 years ago, and even extended support ended 3 years and 4 months ago.
